# Checking whether a pdf file is present on the url?

Tags: php, curl

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
$url  = 'http://www.some.url/file.pdf';
$path = 'files/file.pdf';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
file_put_contents($path, $data);
?>
```

This is the code that I use to download a particular pdf file froma given url.
What if there a many files in that url by names file1.pdf, file2.pdf etc. How can I check while running a loop, when to end the loop as the files will be present up to a limited number ?

Please help!

Comment: You end when you get 404 or whatever error the site is designed to throw.

Comment: @Subir Kumar Sao how to check that in php ... ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checking for 404 code:

```
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if($httpCode == 404) {
    /* file NOT found */
}
```

Checking mime type:

```
$mimeType = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
if($mimeType == 'application/pdf') {
    /* It IS pdf file */
}
```

But note, that mime type can be other, but it'll be still PDF file! Also, check mime type by your PDF files: `echo` them to understand what u must look for. I'm not rly sure, that code in `if` statement is right (it is **example** only)

You can call `curl_get_info()` right after `curl_exec()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
pass image link inside file_get_contents();
then check using preg_match();
<?php $link = $image->img1;
$filecontent=file_get_contents($link);
if(preg_match("/^%PDF-1.5/", $filecontent)){
    echo "Valid pdf";
}else{
    echo "In Valid pdf";
}
?>

You can also check: to get last three character of your file

<?php
$img_type = substr($image->img1, -3); ?> 
<?php if(preg_match("/^%PDF-1.5/", $filecontent) || $img_type == 'pdf' ){ }?>
```